# Jsonschema Title Pattern

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How to validate jsonschema with a [titled pattern](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html), e.g. words start with uppercase characters, all remaining cased characters have lowercase.

My attempt so far does almost work, only there is a required space on the tail:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]+ )+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with removing the last space.

```
^([A-Z][a-z]+)+$
```

**EDIT**

If you need the space between each word, this should work.

```
^([A-Z][a-z]+ )+[A-Z][a-z]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

not super elegant:

```
^(([A-Z][a-z]* )*[A-Z][a-z])+$
```